# Why is EXPECT_CALL causing a read access violation GMock?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

EDIT: I'm not the only one having this issue, maybe it's VS https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2628

I'm having trouble getting GMock setup correctly. I'm using Windows and CMake, and adding GMock to my existing project.

The code that I'm trying to run is:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using ::testing::AnyNumber;

namespace ifac
{
    class Foo
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() = default;

        virtual void Bar(int i) = 0;
    };

    class FooMock : public Foo
    {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD1(Bar, void(int));
    };


    TEST(FooTest, BarCalled)
    {
        FooMock m;
        EXPECT_CALL(m, Bar(1)).Times(AnyNumber());

        m.Bar(1);
    }
}
```

When it runs I get an error saying:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB.
```

The error is in the `void Mutex::ThreadSafeLazyInit()` of gtest-port.cc.

This seems to only happen if I set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to 17 too. I'm not really sure where to start with this, since I don't know a lot about C++, CMake or gtest/gmock.

Here's a stripped down version of the CMakeLists.txt files I have.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("TestingDemo")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory("googletest")

add_executable(Tests
    "Main.cpp"
    "Tests.cpp")

target_link_libraries(Tests PUBLIC gtest gtest_main gmock gmock_main)

add_test(RunTests Tests)
```

Comment: Could you please provide your CMake code, and build commands in your question post?

Comment: I've added it to the original post. I took out a lot of the other stuff, but if you were to add the Test.cpp file above, the main for gtest, it should produce the same result. I don't have any build commands AFAIK, I just run it from VS.